# Flutter - Android app's size increated as double when I increated minSdkVersion

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-min-sdk

My Flutter app's size increated as double when I increased my minSdkVersion from `minSdkVersion 21` to `minSdkVersion 24`

before updgrading the version my app size was as 36.6 MB
after upgrading the version app size is increated to 77.3 MB

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.yyyyyyy"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
    ......
    ......
    }
```

> **Beofre Upgrading the version**

[image]

> **After Upgrading the version**

[image]